# Function doesn't execute properly inside of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function inside of JavaScript that is supposed to calculate the total price of the product selected inside of php. When I load my page, the console logs outside of my function work but the ones inside don't. Do I have a mistake in my code that causes it to not execute?

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['id']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Article']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Prix']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['PrixRetour']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['QuantiteeMaximale']); ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlentities($row['Projet']); ?></td>
          <td><input data-price='<?= floatval($row['Prix']); ?>' data-max-quantity='<?= intval($row['QuantiteeMaximale']); ?>' type="number" name="quantity"></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <p>Grand Total: $<span id='grandTotal'></span></p>
    <script>
        console.log("test1");
        function calTotal() {
            console.log("test2");
            const tableEl = document.getElementById('articles')
            const grandTotalEl = document.getElementById('grandTotal')
            const inputEls = tableEl.querySelectorAll('input[name=quantity]')
            const updateGrandTotal = (grandTotalEl, inputEls) => {
                grandTotalEl.innerText = inputEls.reduce((total, inputEl) => {
                    const maxQuantity = parseInt(inputEl.dataset.maxQuantity)

                    if(parseInt(inputEl.value) > maxQuantity) inputEl.value = maxQuantity
                    if(parseInt(inputEl.value) < 0) inputEl.value = 0

                    const price = parseFloat(inputEl.dataset.price)
                    const quantity = parseInt(inputEl.value)

                    console.log("hello");

                    if(isNaN(quantity)) return total

                    return total + (price * quantity)
                }, 0)
            }
            console.log("test3");

            quantityInputEls.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keyup', () => updateGrandTotal(grandTotalEl, inputEls)))
        };
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Oops, that's not the problem! You are not calling `calTotal` you are just defining it :)

Comment: How can i call it as soon as my script launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your function with

```
(function calTotal() { 
    //...contents
})();
```

Which will convert the function definition to IIFE, and your event listeners will be bound.

[What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Or just add `calTotal();` just before `</script>`

and move these lines into the event handler, or make them globally accessible:

```
const grandTotalEl = document.getElementById('grandTotal')
const inputEls = tableEl.querySelectorAll('input[name=quantity]')
```

---

Ok, change your code like this:

```
<script> 
    function calTotal() {
        const updateGrandTotal = () => {
            const tableEl = document.getElementById('articles')
            const grandTotalEl = document.getElementById('grandTotal')
            const inputEls = tableEl.querySelectorAll('input[name=quantity]')
            grandTotalEl.innerText = inputEls.reduce((total, inputEl) => {
                const maxQuantity = parseInt(inputEl.dataset.maxQuantity)
                if(parseInt(inputEl.value) > maxQuantity) inputEl.value = maxQuantity
                else if(parseInt(inputEl.value) < 0) inputEl.value = 0

                const price = parseFloat(inputEl.dataset.price)
                const quantity = parseInt(inputEl.value)

                console.log("hello");

                if(isNaN(quantity)) return total

                return total + (price * quantity)
            }, 0)
        }

        quantityInputEls.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('keyup', () => updateGrandTotal(grandTotalEl, inputEls)))
    };
</script>
```

Then you can debug it at your developer tools window to see what's not working.

Comment: Well now my console log work but it still doesn't give me the total. Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I put these lines before the calTotal, but it still doesn't return the total. I can't seem to find the error in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create javascript-only function for loaded DOM
function readyFired(callback) {
    document.readyState != 'complete' ? setTimeout('readyFired(' + callback + ')', 1) : callback();
}

// DOM is fully-loaded and ready to calculate the total
readyFired(function() {
    calTotal();
});
```